# How to mock an external dependency without common interface for unit test in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, c++17, static-polymorphism

I need to mock an external dependency for unit test since it is not deterministic.

The dependency class cannot be abstracted out with an interface and dependency-injected into the constructor since it is in a 3rd party library. Another reason it can't use a common interface for inheritance is that the functions I need to call from this dependency are template functions.

The other option is to do template-based dependency injection into my system under test. Unfortunately, this means that my system under test class is a template class and requires all the code to be in the header. Other than toy examples, it is not tractable to have my SUT class which contains domain logic and complex code to reside entirely in a header. It seems template-based dependency injection methods require the SUT to be entirely header-based which is a severe limitation. Am I wrong here?

I have tried using template injection for my unit test but I can't get away from my SUT class not being a template class.

What are my options?

Comment: Your only option is to figure it out, that's it. C++ is just too complicated, and each individual code base works in a unique ways. This kind of a question is too broad and opinionated for an authoritative answer that can be answered with facts and citation. I would only suggest paying less attention to buzzword bingo, and more attention to functional requirements and the actual code.

Comment: "It seems template-based dependency injection methods require the SUT to be entirely header-based which is a severe limitation. Am I wrong here?" - yes, you can avoid this by using explicit instantiation definitions. See the latter part of the answer to the linked-to duplicate question.

Comment: @dfrib But it's not always the case that SUT will know which classes it is going be injected with apriori so it can do explicit template instantiation

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not looking for any authoritative answers. I'm just looking for options or examples that might point me in the right direction i.e. how I can mock my dependency with the constraints I have, in my actual code? Yes, my option is to figure it out but I was hoping for some concrete examples that might help me.

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for opinions, or code examples are not considered to be [appropriate questions for Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)(see third prohibited topic), this is a question/answer site for ***technical programming questions*** that can be answered with facts and citations.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok. I don't see how the 3rd prohibited topic 'recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource' really applies to my question. I'm not asking for recommendations for a tool or book but asking about a specific programming problem. But if that is your understanding so be it. I don't want to argue about it.

Comment: @dfrib I am trying to see if I can use the suggestions in the linked-to question. Your answer still seems to indicate that all the definitions are in b-timpl.h and the b.cpp just includes this header and adds the explicit template instantiation. All the code is still in the header. I understand this will work but it still is weird to someone reading the code.

Comment: @atab The key is that `b-timpl.h` is not a public-facing header. Some who are using this technique name it `b.tpp` or `b-timpl.cpp` etc. The client-facing header `b.h` will not include the definitions, and the translation units of the client including `b.h` will not get bloated by the definitions of the entities of `b.h` - these will reside in the translation unit of `b.cpp` (which includes `b-timpl.h`).

Comment: @dfrib Thanks for clarifying. The bottom line is that the definitions all reside in a non-public-facing header file and I guess you can call it a cpp file. It's a useful technique. Since, I have developers who will be writing several of these types of classes, they will have to understand this pattern too. Do you happen to have a public-facing compilable example of this pattern?